# Colored Checkbox, Group box and etc

Tags: c++, winapi

I colored static lables with this way:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
    DWORD CtrlID = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam); //Window Control ID

    if(OptionColored)
    {
        HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;
        SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255,255,255));
        SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(70,70,70));
        return (INT_PTR)hBrush;
    }
}
```

Now, how can I color checkboxs and groupboxs ?

Edit:
When I try with this code to change the color, background woring. text color not.

Answer (score 1):

try playing with these messages:

```
WM_CTLCOLORBTN
WM_CTLCOLOREDIT
WM_CTLCOLORDLG
WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX
WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR
WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC //You are already using
```

I know that you need to handle `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` to color check boxes <strike>but not sure which one is it for a groupbox.</strike> and it should also work for group boxes as those inherit from `CButton`

Also noticed in your code that you are checking for (`OptionColored`), not sure what that is but you need to check if the message is targeted to your desired control to color.

so instead of checking `if(OptionColored)`, you need something like:

```
DWORD CtrlID = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam));
if (CtrlID == IDC_STATIC1) //If desired control
    {
       //Color my STATIC CONTROLE
    }
```

Comment: OptionColored its just s define of few IDs (like IDC_STATIC1), And can you show me how to do that with the WM_CTLCOLORBTN I tried. But it didn't worked.

Comment: @user2112317 are you using MFC or plain WinAPI?

Comment: Then you should just add another check in your wndproc override for wm_ctlcolorbtn

Comment: case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
  {
   DWORD CtrlID = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam); //Window Control ID
   HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;

   if (CtrlID == IDC_CHECK_CHAT)
   {
    SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255,255,255));
    SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(70,70,70));
    return (INT_PTR)hBrush;
   }


         if(!hColorBrush) hColorBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(70 , 70, 70));
         return (LRESULT)hColorBrush;
  }

Comment: Check the documentation of `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761849(v=vs.85).aspx). Note this remark `"Buttons with the **BS_PUSHBUTTON**, **BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON**, or **BS_PUSHLIKE** styles do not use the returned brush....."` does any of these apply to your case??

Comment: Here how my checkbox looks in the .rc file:
    CONTROL         "Disable the program when you in-chat",IDC_CHECK_CHAT,
                    "Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,16,134,137,10

Comment: I think its best if you edit your question and post your `WndProc` code to have a look at it.

Comment: can you post the whole thing including both `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` and `WM_CTLCOLORBTN`

Comment: are you using `BS_OWNERDRAW` when creating the checkbox? I think thats your problem right there...

Comment: No, You can see that I posted the checkbox (how he written on the .rc files)

Comment: Sorry, did not notice.. you should have appended that to your question. Then have you tried adding the ownerdraw flag?

Comment: If I'll add that, I won't be able to see the checkbox :/

Comment: In Duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214237/checkbox-change-the-text-color there is a fine solution