# Checkbox change the text color

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

The background changed, but the text color not.
here my code:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
    DWORD CtrlID = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam); //Window Control ID

    if(CtrlID == IDC_CHECK_CHAT)
    {
        HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;
        SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255,255,255));
        SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(70,70,70));
        return (INT_PTR)hBrush;
    }
}
```

resource file:

```
CONTROL         "Blah Blah Blah",IDC_CHECK_CHAT,
                "Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,24,72,137,10
```

Comment: What is Checkbox defined as? More typically you'd compare against IDC_CHECK_CHAT directly...

Comment: IDC_CHECK_CHAT = 'Checkbox' let me change it that it will be more clear ..

Comment: Might need to see more of your message switch. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525669/set-static-text-color-win32?rq=1 to see if the suggestions there help you out.

Comment: The answer below is much more useful than the one that is linked to (at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095728/colored-checkbox-group-box-and-etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to first remove theme with SetWindowTheme:

```
HWND hwndCheckbox = GetDlgItem(_hdlg, IDC_CHECK_CHAT);
SetWindowTheme(hwndCheckbox, L"wstr", L"wstr");
```

before you could color the text.

Comment: Er, what is this theme names `wstr`?

Comment: just an non-exists theme name could do the job.

Comment: Very helpful -- but note that one shouldn't call SetWindowTheme from within the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC handler code.  Otherwise an infinite loop is likely.