# Changing win32's radio button text color

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Upon color change, i listen to WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC and act accordingly:

```
LRESULT ProcessWindowMessage(_In_ HWND hWnd, _In_ UINT uMsg, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
            LRESULT lBrush = ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // get default brush used so far
            ::SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
            ::SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(m_color.red, m_color.green, m_color.blue));
            return lBrush;
        }
    }
```

This works well with regular static-texts: labels and so on, but has no effect on regular radio buttons.

During my debugging attempts, I've tried listening to:

1. WM_DRAWITEM - doesn't receive any events
2. WM_CTLCOLORBTN - receive events only for regular push buttons( OK / CANCEL)
3. WM_CTLCOLOREDIT - doesn't receive any events.

I'm subclassing to another window not generated / created by me, but constructed by my process.

Comment: You don't get to control these colours when themes are active.

Comment: Button controls support `NM_CUSTOMDRAW`, perhaps it's possible to change the text colour that way (I've never tried).

Comment: Why dont you handle WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBKGNDand draw it ur self

Comment: @TonyThomas, it arrives only once, and not for the specified ctrl

Comment: @DavidHeffernan mind providing a link describing this?

Comment: What more is there to say. When themes are active, the theme determines the colours.

Comment: maybe refer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214237/checkbox-change-the-text-color/15214715#15214715

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, if we draw the control fully, it will override the theme

Comment: @Tony Yes. That's the only way.

Comment: Seriously though, overriding the theme is not "hard". Use `DrawThemeBackground` to draw the radio button shape and `DrawText` to draw the text. Not rocket science.

Comment: @Jichao, i tried SetWindowTheme(ctrl.GetWindow(), L"koko", nullptr) which returned with S_OK,  and later on set a new color to the control. Changing this had no affect on the control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@igal k said SetWindowTheme does not work. Since the comment is not enough for the sample code. I post it as an answer.

First the result.

[image]

Code:

```
OnInitDialog:
    ::SetWindowTheme(GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO1)->GetSafeHwnd(), L"wstr", L"wstr");

HBRUSH CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    // Call the base class implementation first! Otherwise, it may 
    // undo what we're trying to accomplish here.
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    // Are we painting the IDC_MYSTATIC control? We can use 
    // CWnd::GetDlgCtrlID() to perform the most efficient test. 
    if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_RADIO1)
    {
        // Set the text color to red
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));

        // Set the background mode for text to transparent  
        // so background will show thru.
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

        // Return handle to our CBrush object
        hbr = m_brush;
    }

    return hbr;
}
```

Comment: @Jicaho, That made the trick! in addition, i also discovered that instead of calling the original WndProc function, i accidentally called ::DefWindowProc()...

Comment: ::SetWindowTheme call is to prevent any visual styles (themes) to be applied to the radio button and will work with empty strings too. Otherwise SetTextColor() might not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to draw the full radio button, what you have to do is  set a custom window proc for the radio button.In that proc you get the WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBKGND messages. 
In the erase background you can just fill the background color for the control.

In WM_PAINT you do the drawing of the control , get the window text of the control and do a DrawText with color set to whatever you need using SetTextColor

Draw an image of radio (circle and a dot inside).You can get all the state variables of the control and draw according to it, like whether its selected it or not. Whenever you need a repaint, ie new text is set, just call invalidateRect to force a repaint..

Comment: What about [Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773187.aspx)?

Comment: 1999 called, they want their answer back