# Win32 - Color static text (WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, text, colors

I have this code

```
BOOL CALLBACK msgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam 
{
    static HBRUSH hBrush = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE);
    switch(message) {
    ...
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
       HDC hdc = (HDC) wParam; // Updated
       SetBkMode(hdc,TRANSPARENT);
       if(GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_ID ) == IDC_RADIO_EXCELLENT) {
          // Dark green.
          SetTextColor(hdc,RGB(0,0x64,0));
       }
       return (LRESULT) hBrush; 
    case ...        
    }

}
```

I'm trying to color the static text to darkgreen. I am sure, that SetTextColor is called.

Everything is ok but when I use:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

then static text is not dark green but black.

What I am doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution which works me.
Set off visual style for radio button in WM_INITDIALOG for dialog.

```
SetWindowTheme(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_RADIO_EXCELLENT), L"", L"");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing win32's radio button text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854015/changing-win32s-radio-button-text-color)

Comment: You cannot use this code to color controls, when using [Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773187.aspx).

Comment: You are enabling themes.  Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I found some solution, so I updated my question with solution.

Comment: @JaroKollár Rather than editing your question with the solution, please post it as an answer to your own question - doing so is perfectly fine practice on SO.